# SOLVED Xamarin Forms Datepicker doesn't work for Android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker

I checked everywhere and couldn't find any solutions.

I have a Datepicker in my XAML in a Xamarin app. When I debug the app the Datepicker on iOS works perfectly without any problem but with Android it does'nt, I tried with an emulator (Android 5) with a phone (Android 9).

In details what happens is when I click on the date to pick a date nothing happens, literaly. Nothing that's all.

There is nothing in my code, I'll post it here.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Label Text="Publication Date" WidthRequest="70" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0" />
     <DatePicker x:Name="Date" MaximumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" Date="{Binding PublicationDate}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="True"  Margin="10,0"/>
</StackLayout>
```

EDIT : I changed my Datepicker place and it works but in the my StackLayout no.

I'll show the structure of the code so you see how it works

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,10" Spacing="15">
        ...
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="Publication Date" WidthRequest="70" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0" />
            <DatePicker x:Name="Date" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="True" Margin="10,0"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    ...

</Grid>
```

*

> If I put it in the first StackLayout (this one):
>        It works but not in the second

- => This is incorrect

EDIT 2:

Something new came out lol, if I replace the first StackLayout with a AbsoluteLayout it works --'

SOLUTION :

Nothing worked so I found a some sort of way out, I just removed the first Stacklayout and add more rows in my Grid. Now everything works.

Comment: DId you try to remove properties and see what happens? `MaximumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"` this looks like it _should_ work, but might cause trouble. Try removing it and see it works then

Comment: Is your PublicationDate nullable ? Try without the MaximumDate or provide the value with binding instead to try ? I use the DatePicker a lot on Android without any problem.

Comment: I tried by removing everything and using just <DatePicker /> and still doesn't work. Did you do all the last updates ? I did maybe it is the problem ?

Comment: @AspirioA You mean that there is a problem with your second part of your code? but I test your code, don't have any question, I can choose data successfully. So if you still have some problem, please post your full code that having question here.

Comment: There is a problem with the Datepicker in the stack layout that is in the other stacklayout. I’m really confused right now, I’ll try to contact Microsoft. Let’s keep the subject open

Comment: Any error in the code behind file?

Comment: @JasminSojitra I have absolutely nothing even in output. It just don't do anything very strange. I'll report it to Microsoft find out what is the problem.

Comment: I made a mistake. None of the new Datepickers that I add works in the stacklayout (all the stacklayouts), but it does in the GRID. Now I'm totally lost lol

Comment: @Aspirio You said that you have contacted with Microsoft, do you get any info about your question? If you still have this question, can your upload your sample at github, I will download your sample to test?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Sorry for this late response :') I had no news from Microsoft so I just avoid using DatePicker in the stacklayout :')